# jsoup fetch element proceeding specific element

Tags: jsoup

Is it possible to get proceeding element using jSoup by knowing the previous element?

for example in this html, I have the data of table "**Given this item**"
I would like to fetch the next table containing "**Looking for this**"

```
<table><tr><td>irrelevant info 1 <a href="http://jsoup.org/">jsoup</a></td></tr></table>
<p>there is a p here</p>
<table><tr><td>Given this item <a href="http://jsoup.org/">jsoup</a></td></tr></table>
<p>there is a p here</p>
<table><tr><td>Looking for this <a href="http://jsoup.org/">jsoup</a></td></tr></table>
<p>there is a p here</p>
<table><tr><td>irrelevant info 2<a href="http://jsoup.org/">jsoup</a></td></tr></table>
<p>there is a p here</p>
<table><tr><td>irrelevant info 3 <a href="http://jsoup.org/">jsoup</a></td></tr></table>
```

example:
http://try.jsoup.org/~vtmUE0bVgNHSxdvpKcIzpL3pHEA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can use list.indexOf

```
Elements tables = doc.select("table");// returns a list of all table elements
Element given = doc.select("table:contains(Given this item)").first(); //yor given element
Element required = tables.get(tables.indexOf(given)+1);//index of given + 1 = index of required element
```

Answer (score 1):

The way your HTML is structured is like this:
If we use the following selector - `Element e = doc.select("tr:contains(Given this item)").first();` we will get

```
<tr>
 <td>Given this item <a href="http://jsoup.org/">jsoup</a></td>
</tr>
```

Now, the parent of this element, given by `e.parents().first()` is

```
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td>Given this item <a href="http://jsoup.org/">jsoup</a></td>
 </tr> 
</tbody>
```

And its parent - `e.parents().first().parents().first()` is

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>Given this item <a href="http://jsoup.org/">jsoup</a></td>
  </tr> 
 </tbody>
</table>`
```

And now you can get your sibling like that - `e.parents().first().parents().first().nextElementSibling()` which results with

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>Looking for this <a href="http://jsoup.org/">jsoup</a></td>
  </tr> 
 </tbody>
</table>
```

But its pretty ugly... so instead you can query for `Elements e = doc.select("table:contains(Given this item)");` to get

```
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>Given this item <a href="http://jsoup.org/">jsoup</a></td>
  </tr> 
 </tbody>
</table>`
```

and then the element you are looking for is `e.first().nextElementSibling()`.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you TDG

According to [jsoup cookbook](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax)

siblingA ~ siblingX: finds sibling X element preceded by sibling A, e.g. h1 ~ p

So I ended up doing:

```
table:contains(Given this item)  ~ table
```

And then I took e.first()

Comment: That's odd - I've tried to use `~` but for some reason I did not get the expected result.

Comment: please add this to your solution  - I will accept it.

Comment: But it didn't workes for me, so I've used the method described in my answer. There is no need that you'll accept me answer. If your solution works, you should accept it, so other users will know that it solved your problem.